# Парсер. Как пропустить строку с ошибкой

Tags: python, парсер

Есть .txt файл с массивом типовых строк

Я пытаюсь вытащить определенное значение из каждой строки проходя сторки вот так:

```
import re

with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    m = re.findall("'(.+?)'", line)
    print(m[3])
```

Все работает как нужно. Проблема начинается когда одна из строк не соответствует условию и тогда появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 79, in <module>
    print(m[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Собственно вопрос: я хочу чтоб строка которая не соответствует - просто отбрасывалась и цикл шел дальше просто отбрасывая несоответствующие строки

Comment: Проблема решилась, но появилась другая: файл txt с массивом настолько большой, что съедается вся оперативная память

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    m = re.findall("'(.+?)'", line)
    print(m[3])
except IndexError:
    continue
```

Comment: Лучше в блок `try` внести и саму регулярку, потому что ошибка может выскакивать в ней.